# How do I set a minimum width and height for my Silverlight 4 OOB application?

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

Is there a way to set a minimum width and height for my Silverlight 4 out-of-browser application?

Comment: what exactly problems you faced??? because this is simple thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no built in settings to control the window Minimum Width and Height so you will need to handle it with code.

First of all your OOB app needs to have Elevated Trust.

You then need to attach a handler the `SizeChanged` event of the `FrameworkElement` being used for the application's `RootVisual` (usually MainPage.xaml).

In the handler include code like this:-

```
 if (Application.MainWindow.Width < myMinWidth)
     Application.MainWindow.Width = myMinWidth;

 if (Application.MainWindow.Height < myMinHeight)
     Application.MainWindow.Height = myMinHeight;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set directly properties only... You can set properties of Window with minimum and maximum. or else you can programmatically set it in PageLoad/form load Event.