# How to set minimum width and height in a silverlight OOB application?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, expression-blend

I am trying to set a minimum width and height for my silverlight 4 OOB application without any success so far.
Can someone help me as i keep getting this error messages:

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field,method, or property 'kat.MainPage.Width.get' and 'kat.MainPage.Height.get'

My code is the following:

```
namespace kat
{
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.SizeChanged +=new System.Windows.SizeChangedEventHandler(LayoutRoot_SizeChanged);
    }

    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    private void LayoutRoot_SizeChanged(object sender, System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (kat.MainPage.Width <500)
        kat.MainPage.Width =500;
      if (kat.MainPage.Height <500)
        kat.MainPage.Height =500;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215421/how-do-i-set-a-minimum-width-and-height-for-my-silverlight-4-oob-application. Notice how he uses "Application.MainWindow."

Comment: Question is a duplicate, but their problem is more syntax than anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume kat is just your namespace...

You are basically trying to access members of an object without actually using a pointer to the object. `kat.MainPage` is a class, not an object so any references to `kat.MainPage.anything` will fail with that error.

You just wanted:

```
private void LayoutRoot_SizeChanged(object sender, System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.MainWindow.Width < 500)
        Application.MainWindow.Width = 500;
    if (Application.MainWindow.Height < 500)
        Application.MainWindow.Height = 500;
}
```